# Showing track name and artist for music, podcasts and any apps [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, audio, mpmusicplayercontroller

I've been trying to find a way to access the track name and artist information from any background audio just like the iOS control center player (swipe up view).

I have a part of my app that needs to display the track name and artist of any current music playing in the background.

At the moment I've been testing the MPMusicPlayerController but I can only get it to provide the now playing item of the Music app and not other third-party apps like Spotify or Apple's podcast app.

Any idea how I can replicate the control centers ability to fetch now playing items from any app music using the play audio background mode?

I'm trying to get this working in swift.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting which audio track is playing on device in iOS Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581548/detecting-which-audio-track-is-playing-on-device-in-ios-swift)